# Continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Online with Azure Virtual Machines

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, azure, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I need Continuous delivery to Azure virtual machines(not cloud service or websites) using Visual Studio Online

Here is the link for Continuous delivery - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

Is this possible with Azure Virtual Machines?

My another question is which one is best Azure Virtual Machines, Cloud services or Websites? My application is big business application which is built in asp.net 4.5 and SQL server 2012 so I wanted to 
know which one is best with the "Continuous delivery"

Answer (score 0):

The continuous delivery you are talking about can be achieved in an Infrastructure as a service(IAAS , Virtual machines) scenario as well as in  Platform as a Service ( PAAS ,Azure websites) scenario.
1. In  case you want to have control on the platform, runtime , roles etc. and you decided to go he IAAS route your CI/CD setup will be no different from a on-premises machine  deployed , the deployment  destination changes to an Azure VM instead of local machine.

2.If you decided to offload the OS/runtime/Environment management to Azure and are only taking care of your application deployment ,  azure still supports CI/CD using the KUDU engine.  And slots( Dev/Staging) could be configured for continuous deployment. You can setup continuous deployment or you may want to deploy your app in a staging slot for validation and promote to PROD when things look good.

CI/CD in Azure VM - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/architecture/cicd-for-azure-vms/

CI/CD  for Azure Websites - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/architecture/vsts-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-for-azure-web-apps/